# DLL file size becoming 0 kb after first execution on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, dll

I have an aspx application on a IIS server (windows server 2012 R2) that has been working 3 years ago without any problem. However yesterday when accessing the main aspx page, everyone started getting an error saying that namespace 'objectstore' doesn't exist. The namespace 'objectstore' is present on a library that I add a reference to in my aspx project.
What is really weird is after adding the reference, the reresh file gets the correct path and it works when you refresh the page, when you do a second refresh. It says that the namespace doesn't exist and the dll file I added becomes 0 kb in the bin folder.

I tried 
    cleaning up the IIS temp files and restarting IIS and restarting the server
    Rebuilding the whole project and giving permissions to all the external dll folders
    Changing the dll name without changing the namespace and rebuilding
    Disabled Kaspersky and added an exception on the specific dll file
    Viewing the dll logs, nothing throws an error.

I didn't find anything on stackoverflow or google related to this issue. Any thoughts are welcome..

EDIT: Adding the Library as a project seems to resolve the problem for now, but it still weird how the DLL File was emptied. I will try to reproduce the issue to see what the problem was.

EDIT 2: Thanks for the tip guys, after running procmon I found out that the DLL was being deleted from the code (someone deleted it on purpose), I know someone had issues ... but I think this problem would never occur for other people, but the answer is kind of informative. You learn a lot using procmon.

Thanks in advance,
Reda

Comment: Sounds still suspiciously like the dll being quarantiened - maybe Windows Defender?

Comment: Yes that's what I thought but why it has been working since 3 years ago. And just now the DLL gets deleted. I ll try and disable all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To investigate on who is rewriting your DLL files I suggest you to use the [SysInternal Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) configured for monitoring only your file path.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you I will monitor the library dll to see what's happening.